# Pushing a button (from far away)

Tags: java, bukkit

So what I am doing is, I am checking if the player right clicks air using the `PlayerInteractEvent`, then I am getting the player's target block and saving it as a variable named "block".

This all is working fine but what i want to do with this is check if that block is a button and if so "push" it, but it isn't doing that right.

I have tried casting the block to `org.bukkit.material.Button` after checking if its type was indeed a button, then I set it to powered like so:
`((Button) block.getState().getData()).setPowered(true);`, but that didn't do anything so I then tried: `block.setData((byte) (block.getData() | 0x8)));`, and that did turn it on but it stayed on.

So how do I do this correctly?

Here is the full code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteraction(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR)) {
        Block block = e.getPlayer().getTargetBlock((Set<Material>) null, 200);
        if (block.getType().equals(Material.STONE_BUTTON) || block.getType().equals(Material.WOOD_BUTTON)) {
            block.setData((byte) (block.getData() | 0x8));
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I am using the `Spigot 1.12.2 API`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to trigger `RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK` action, because Button is a block. Secondly, event called before you push the button, so if you want to change the state of buttom after player clicked, you should run task later to change it a bit later after event passed.

Also, you don't need to check hand item type point to null. If `ItemStack` is not null, `Material` will never be null, and in case if ItemStack will be null, you will catch NPE, trying to get `Material`. And in versions 1.9 and above you might also check `EquipmentSlot`, because `PlayerInteractEvent` calls twice (as hand and offhand).

```
ItemStack item = e.getPlayer().getInventory().getItemInMainHand();
if (e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) && e.getHand() == EquipmentSlot.HAND 
        && (item == null || item.getType() == Material.AIR)) {
    // Your code
}
```

To change button state in new way, get `MaterialData` from the block state, cast it to `Button`, change power state, write all back to block and update:

```
Button button = (Button) block.getState().getData();
button.setPowered(true);
block.getState().setData(button);
block.getState().update();
```

Furthermore, you don't really need to check facing at block, if `Action` is `RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK`, then you can get it directly from event.

```
Block block = e.getClickedBlock();
```

So, I think, the final code may looks like that:

```
Plugin plugin = Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("YourPluginName");
ItemStack item = e.getPlayer().getInventory().getItemInMainHand();
if (e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) && e.getHand() == EquipmentSlot.HAND 
        && (item == null || item.getType() == Material.AIR)) {
    Block block = e.getClickedBlock();
    Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Button button = (Button) block.getState().getData();
            button.setPowered(true);
            block.getState().setData(button);
            block.getState().update();
        }
    }, 2L);
}
```

Comment: Ah, so, you need to add ignore cancelled, because right click in air event automatically cancelled by bukkit. Try `@EventHandler(ignoreCancelled = true)`.

Comment: The comment box says "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements." Simply saying "this doesn't work" doesn't help find out what is wrong.

Comment: Okay well i figured out how to click a button, but now i have another issue which is detecting a right click on air when the player has no item in hand.